# Fill Down Average Every X Rows Across Multiple Columns

Tags: excel

I have an Excel sheet with the following format:

```
Var Run P U
0   1   7 2
0   2   8 2
0   3   8 2
1   1   9 10
1   2   9 15
1   2   9 20
```

The top left of the data is at cell `A1`. Each variable has three runs with information about variables collected. I need to collect the average and sample variance about each `Var` and have currently been doing so by hand, but would like to do this automatically with a pulldown. I would like to create another group of data with the top left in cell A10. This would have format

```
Var Avg.P Var.S.P Avg.U Var.S.U
0   2     ... 
1   1.66  ...
```

Ideally when I add more variables with three runs, I could just drag down to perform these calculations. I have experimented with `OFFSET` to do this, but all my attempts have failed, which is why I turn to SO for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use Index to achieve the same result:

```
=IFERROR(AVERAGE(INDEX(A$2:A$10,(ROWS(A11:A$11)-1)*3+1):INDEX(A$2:A$10,(ROWS(A11:A$11)-1)*3+3)),"")
```

[image]

If you insert more rows, the formulas will shift down and update themselves:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Something along the lines of `=VAR.S(OFFSET($C$2,(ROW()-2)*3,,3,))` solved this.